# Can't create an instance of the OracleDataSource class

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jdeveloper

I'm working on a Java app, trying to create an instance of the `OracleDataSource`. I've seen a bunch of posts saying the Oracle drivers aren't in Maven Central but according to [this](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html), they are now. So here's the dependency in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then in my class I have:

```
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

...

public void someMethod() {
    ...
    OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
    ...
}
```

But I get errors saying neither the packages nor the class exist.

> Error: package oracle.jdbc.pool does not exist.
>
> Type 'OracleDataSource' not found

What am I missing here? It's been a while since I last worked with Java and Maven so I figure it's something simple.

**EDIT**
The IDE (JDeveloper) and Maven seem to be out of sync. I'm getting different errors running Maven commands.

Comment: Quote exactly the error message.

Comment: @BasilBourque added to the question

Comment: I tried the dependency and OracleDataSource instantiation as above and it compiled and ran in IntelliJ and on command line (mvn clean package) on Java 11.0.12-open. Are you getting the error during compilation? Have you checked if the jar file is in your .m2 repository, or has it cached a previous failure to retrieve it. Is the error in an IDE (I sometimes find IntelliJ gets a bit out of kilter). Have you tried temporarily moving the contents of you .m2/repository directory then doing an mvn clean package at the terminal?

Comment: Yes, what Chris commented: Maven and/or IntelliJ frequently go bonkers. Frustrating, and disappointing, but the workaround is easy as Chris noted. Delete the `.m2` folder, and then do a Maven `clean`. Another possible solution is to do “Invalidate caches” in IntelliJ. You can search Stack Overflow to find other posts about these.

Comment: @Chris I'm using JDeveloper unfortunately and you're right there's a disconnect between the IDE and the real world. I was getting the error from the IDE's syntax highlighting but the compilation errors were different. Solved those and now it compiles but I still have errors in the IDE. Feel free to drop your comment as an answer.

Comment: Ah thanks - will do  in case anyone else hits the same problem (there's not much useful that comes back from a general internet search). Certainly with IntelliJ I find there isn't an entirely clear boundary between the outside maven view of the world and the internal IntelliJ view, which can lead to really frustrating problems

Comment: Yep, I was at a complete loss, didn't know where to start trying to solve this and didn't imagine that the IDE and maven could be completely out of touch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the dependency and OracleDataSource instantiation as above and it compiled and ran in IntelliJ and on command line (mvn clean package) on Java 11.0.12-open, so I believe you are correct that the Oracle drivers are in Maven Central.

It may be an IDE issue - I sometimes find that IntelliJ's internal view of the project and dependencies is slightly out of kilter and either needs cache invalidation or careful gradual rebuild of any modules. I'm not sure what the equivalents are in JDeveloper.

However, generally the best way to deal with strange compilation issues is to first take the IDE out of the equation - try a `mvn clean install` in the terminal. If that fails it may be worth moving your `~/.m2/repository` directory (or just the `~/.m2/repository/com.oracle` directory) and trying again in case a previous failure to retrieve artifacts has been cached. If it still fails then maybe check `~/.m2/settings.xml` to make sure it is pointing to maven central, but I'd expect it to find that driver okay.